# "why there is" Vs ."why is there"

Tags: difference

How should I say:

> **Why there is** only one student there?

or

> **Why is there** only one student there?

Answer (score 6):

According to the basic rules of English question formation, the word that comes after the question word (those are words like *why*, *what*, *where* etc.) is either one of the two auxiliary verbs (*to do* and *to have*), a modal verb (*would*, *might*, *should* etc.) or one of the numerous forms of the verb *to be*. That's why, strictly speaking, only the second sentence is grammatically correct:

```
[question word] [auxiliary verb/modal verb/to be verb] the rest of the sentence?
```

> **Why was** there nobody in the room?

The first sentence as a question is still technically possible, though. You'd most likely hear this in a situation where somebody first uses it as part of a regular declarative statement and then you repeat it with a rising intonation to indicate a mild surprise. In English, as is common across many European languages, a rising intonation is all you need to turn a declarative statement into an interrogative one. A short example dialogue:

> — He wants to know why there is only one student there.
>   — Why there is only one student there? Really? Is that what he wants to know?